# Where to initialize DbContext in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, entity-framework-core

Let's say I'm making an application. For the user interface I decide to go with an Model-View-ViewModel pattern. The UI will access a service layer which will use Entity Framework Core as a replacement for the more traditional repository (I know people have mixed feelings about this, but this is not the point of this question). Preferably the DbContext from EFCore will be injected into the service. Something like this:

```
public void SomeUserInterfaceMethod() 
{
    using (var context = new MyContext()) 
    {
        var service = new MyService(context);
        service.PerformSomeAction();
    }
}
```

Now this isn't so bad at all, but I do have an issue with it. The `using (var context = new MyContext())` will be in **a lot** of places in the code, even in a small application. This means trouble if I want to change the context as well as for testing purposes.

Now I could replace the `new MyContext()` with a factory method (`MyFactory.GetMyContext()`), which would make it easier to replace. But what if I want to change the context to a testing one (using another database)?

Is there some more clever way to initialize `MyContext` which allows both for easy replacement, but also for easy testing?

Comment: I think Dependency Injection is probably the least headache-inducing. There's a sort of 'fire and forget' aspect that makes rigging things up pretty easy. While you'll see a fair amount of `using(var context = new MyContext())`, this approach has some advantages to it too. Like, if you wanted to introduce parallelism in some way, sharing one context across threads is a recipe for problems. I think the tradeoff is generally worth it, and it's not unusual to see a fair amount of those using statements with contexts out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't see any problems in using factory method for your purposes.

Easy replacement example:

```cs
public class ClassWithSomeUserInterfaceMethod
{
    private readonly IDataContextsFactory dataContextsFactory;

    public ClassWithSomeUserInterfaceMethod(IDataContextsFactory dataContextsFactory)
    {
        this.dataContextsFactory = dataContextsFactory;
    }

    public void SomeUserInterfaceMethod() 
    {
        using (var context = dataContextsFactory.GetDataContext()) 
        {
            var service = new MyService(context);
            service.PerformSomeAction();
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass any class that implements `IDataContextsFactory` interface in `dataContextsFactory`.

Easy testing example:

```cs
public AnotherDatabaseDataContextFactory : IDataContextsFactory
{
    public IDataContext GetDataContext()
    {
        return new AnotherDataContext();
    }
}

[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var factory = new AnotherDatabaseDataContextFactory();
    var classWithSomeUserInterfaceMethod = new ClassWithSomeUserInterfaceMethod(factory);

    classWithSomeUserInterfaceMethod.SomeUserInterfaceMethod();

    // Assert.That ...
}
```

Hope it helps.